# Same or different runtime folder for each application?

Tags: php, yii

I'm wondering whether I can use the same runtime folder by placing it in the common folder instead of creating two (or more) runtime folders, one for each application I have (frontend, backend, etc).

I'm following the approch described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site/).

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could reasonably go either way. You can name log files in a common runtime dir to identify the application. Or I suppose you could even have them all log to the same log file if you override CLogRoute::formatLogMessage() to make it identify the application in each log message.

So my answer is: whatever you think will be more convenient in practice.

Btw: the layout yiiframework.com uses is unusually complex. It's a great article for learning but not necessarily a suitable prototype dir structure.